# Is there a way to use the data-splitting function for different types of separators at the same time?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Working with a data sheet with phylogenetic data. Trying to separate information out of it. Problem is it's all in one cell and for me to manually double click, highlight part of the cell I need, copy, double click my spreadsheet, and paste into it would be really painful. Trying to separate to columns so I can just copy/paste from one spreadsheet to another.

So it'll look like this in one cell:

```
cervical vertebrae, postzygapophysis, contact anteriorly: absent(0); present but looks weird (1)
```

I want it to look like, in one row:

```
cervical vertebrae | postzygapophysis | contact anteriorly | absent(0) |  present but looks weird(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at HELP or the pop-up when you enter the `Split` function in sheets, you will see that `[split_by_each]` is an option. When set to `TRUE` it will split by each character in the `delimiter` argument.

So, in your case:

```
=split(A1,",:;",true,true)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for in Googlesheet is split:
Basically, for a single separator, you can simply do:

```
=split(Cell,",")
```

But for multiple separators like yours, put all the separator together:

```
=split(Cell,"separators")
```

For example, say in Cell A1 you put your dirty string there,
`cervical vertebrae, postzygapophysis, contact anteriorly: absent(0); present but looks weird (1)`;
In cell B2, or any other cell, you can type: `=split(Cell,",;:")`

If you need to trim out white spaces if present, then you can use this instead:
`=ArrayFormula(trim(split(A1,",;:")))`

Answer (score 0):

for one row (as mentioned):

```
=SPLIT(A1; ",;:")
```

for array use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A; ",;:")))
```